# which jdbc (connector/j) to install for mac os

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I'm trying to download jdbc connector, but I cannot find mac os from the selection options from the link below:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Where can I download mysql connector for mac os?

Or is it the case that jdbc connector is already installed for mac os?

I'm trying to using logstash to transfer mysql data into elasticsearch.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

MySQL Connector/J is a Java library, and it is a pure Java driver, so it is platform independent. The various installers offered on the download page are just to simplify installation (although generally, installing Java libraries using an installer makes very little sense to me).

For MacOS, you can use 'platform independent' and either download the `tar.gz` or the `zip`, whichever you feel is simpler to unpack.

For development purposes, it would be simpler to use the [MySQL Connector/J Maven dependency](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j), for example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(NOTE: versions 8.0.30 and older use artifactId `mysql-connector-java`).